# Send an email whenever file is deleted from shared folder in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, powershell, smtp

I am running a software on several computers at my workplace and the software can run different audio and video files stored on a shared folder in a central computer. The software runs on windows 7 and every person in my company can add or remove files from the shared folder, but this privilege puts the data at risk. I was thinking of creating an email alert to my self whenever a file is deleted. I have written a windows powershell script for sending me emails from smtp server but how can I hook it up to the event of file or folder deletion in a specific shared folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use IO.FileSystemWatcher to trigger actions on file system events.

First you want to define the folder path:

```
$watchFolderPath = "C:\Users\Public\Documents"
$watchFolderFilter = "*.*"
```

Next you initiate the file watcher:

```
$watcher = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $watchFolderPath, $watchFolderFilter -Property @{
    IncludeSubdirectories = $true
    NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'
    }
```

Then you configure the event for deleted objects:

```
$onDeleted = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher Deleted -SourceIdentifier FileDeleted -Action {
    $FileName = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    $messageBody = "File `"$FileName`" was deleted."
    Send-MailMessage -To me@mydomain.com -Subject "File Deleted" -Body $messageBody -SmtpServer mail.mydomain.com
    }
```

To manually remove the event you can use this:

```
Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier FileDeleted
```

Comment: Why not use `Wait-Event`?

Comment: That would probably work too. Why don't you write something up and submit an answer?